# how to have options in urls in django 2.0

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.0

In Django 1 I used to have url choices like this:

```
url('meeting/(?P<action>edit|delete)/', views.meeting_view, name='meeting'),
```

How I do this in Django 2.0 with the <> syntax:

Maybe something like this?

```
path('meeting/(<action:edit|delete>)/', views.meeting_view, name='meeting'),
```

Comment: You can use `re_path` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path

Comment: @neverwalkaloner If you have to write your own `re_path` instead of being able to use the syntax right out-of-box like it was the case with `1.x` version, this is not an improvement in Django 2, but a regression. I hope there's a better way!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path), your first syntax should work right out-of-the-box.

Anyway here's how you could do with the new syntax:

First file = make a Python package `converters` and add `edit_or_delete.py` with that:

```
import re

class EditOrDeleteConverter:
    regex = '(edit|delete)'

    def to_python(self, value):
        result = re.match(regex, value)
        return result.group() if result is not None else ''

    def to_url(self, value):
        result = re.match(regex, value)
        return result.group() if result is not None else ''
```

And for your `urls.py` file, this:

```
from django.urls import register_converter, path

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.EditOrDeleteConverter, 'edit_or_delete')

urlpatterns = [
    path('meeting/<edit_or_delete:action>/', views.meeting_view, name='meeting'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use verbs in urls to indicate the purpose.  Rather, rely on HTTP verbs such as `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` and handle them in your view.  That way, you can have just one view class handling all those different methods with just one URL.